# How can I remove Unity Hub in Ubuntu?

Tags: unity, linux

I installed Unity Hub 1.4.0 and it works well. For now I want to update the version of Unity. I need to install hub 2.0.0. But when I download the 2.0.0 hub and intsall it always link to 1.4.0 and I want the version Unity 2019.1.10f1. I can't find some uninstall files. How can I remove Hub 1.4.0?

Comment: Presumably you followed [the steps to uninstall software in Ubuntu](https://www.wikihow.com/Uninstall-Ubuntu-Software) — where did you run into trouble making these work?

Comment: Thx! I use "dpkg -l | grep unity" but there is another software name "unity" in ubuntu, and I can't find the Unity game engine or Unity Hub. I installed the Unity Hub not through deb. I also try "find -name "Unity"" sames not find any useful thing!!!

Comment: So then [you searched for how to uninstall the Unity editor in Linux](https://www.google.com/search?q=uninstall+unity+editor+linux) and [found previous Q&A](https://askubuntu.com/questions/673488/how-to-remove-unity3d-game-engine-from-ubuntu-and-its-dependencies) on [this topic](https://forum.unity.com/threads/how-to-uninstall-unity-from-ubuntu.376216/), right? Where did you run into trouble following these leads?

Comment: Probably not, I installed Unity through Unity Hub instead of the sudo command. I first install the Unity Hub installation file, then run the file to install, there's not any uninstall file available.

Comment: By the sounds of it the `hub.desktop` file that links to the application just hasn't been updated, im not on my Ubuntu install atm but the path to it is `/home/your-username/.local/shared/applications/` (I think).

Answer (score 2):

from https://docs.unity3d.com/hub/manual/InstallHub.html#install-hub-linux

Uninstalling the Hub:
To remove the Unity Hub from the system, run the following command:

```
$ sudo apt-get remove unityhub
```

Answer (score 1):

Try deleting the following directories:

```
/home/{your_user_name}/.config/UnityHub

/home/{your_user_name}/.config/Unity Hub
```